# Node module provide as getters & setters

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have the following code which is working OK.
Now I need to add additional properties and functions and export them,
How it's recommended to do it?
lets say I've two functions and two additional properties which I need to export.

properties like
isValid
prop1

```
var internal = require("../plu/internal");
module.exports = {isAvailable: false};

internal.eventEmitter.on('AppA', function () {
    module.exports.isAvailable = true;
});
```

Comment: If you can have a default value on all, you could just do this ```module.exports = {isAvailable: false, something: "Hello", somethingElse: "Hullo"};``` and then have your event setters

Comment: Do you want to extend an existing class? Is this your intention?

Comment: Do you want to export setter and getter functions as properties of the exported object/module?

Comment: @SimoEndre correct this is what I need

Comment: @magnudae - Thanks but how should I do it with the functions also can you provide example?

Comment: @Pho3nixHun - nop I just want to expose properties and functions ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to defined setter and getter methods on an object is to use the `Object.defineProperty` method inside your `internal` module. By exporting the `internal` module you will export the `setter` and `getter` methods too.

```
Object.defineProperty(Internal.prototype, "isAvailable", {
    get : function(){
        return this.available;
    },
    set : function(value){
        this.available = value;
    }
});
```

or in ES6 you can write the same thing as:

```
get isAvailable() {
    return this.available;
}

set isAvailable(value) {
    this.available = value;
}
```

With `Internal.prototype` you are extending the base object prototype with setter and getter methods.

Comment: thanks 1+ so in this case how would you export some function?

Comment: Functions are object properties in javascript, so if you define the setter and getter methods as in my example above, as soon as you export your module you are wrapping these methods too into the exported object. Then you can reference them without to instantiate the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy straight forward way. Correct me if I misunderstood.
This will expose the getters and setters for everyone who requires this file. 
Unless you want to emit changes when they happen and only then this might not be the answer.

```
var available = false;
module.exports = {
  getAvailable: getAvailable,
  setAvailable: setAvailable
}
function getAvailable() { return available;}
function setAvailable(avail) { available = avail;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, if it can solve your problem ?

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

var internal = require("../plu/internal");

exports.isAvailable = false;

internal.eventEmitter.on('AppA', function () {
    exports.isAvailable = true;
});

exports.myTestFunc = function () {
     return "Hello Test";
}

exports.testProperty = true;
```

Comment: Thanks but here you put the export multiple times there is a way to send it like an object with all the properties?